# Connecting to SFTP via SSIS

Tags: ssis, sftp, winscp, ssis-2012

I'm trying to connect to a `SFTP` server via an `SSIS` package. The package executes `WinSCP` with the following connection string in a `.txt` file:

```
open sftp://username:fc$#6444@example.com:22
```

However the package keeps failing without being able to connect. Is it something to do with the special characters in the password?

I am able to connect to a different SFTP if I replace the string so I know it must be something to do with the syntax above. I've tried putting double quotes around the string as follows without any success:

```
open "sftp://username:fc$#6444@example.com:22"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to do this too, for one of my work projects recently. We used the <kbd>WinSCP .NET assembly</kbd> inside an SSIS Scripting Task, as this is what WinSCP also recommends as the way to achieve SFTP using WinSCP in SSIS.

See this guide - [Using WinSCP .NET Assembly from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis). It walks you through the install and setup and also contains working sample code (after you change the script to your needs of course!).

Sample code - after you reference the `WinSCPnet.dll` assembly - is below.

```csharp
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask;
using System.AddIn;
using WinSCP;

namespace ST_5a30686e70c04c5a8a93729fd90b8c79.csproj
{
    [AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                // To setup these variables, go to SSIS > Variables.
                // To make them accessible from the script task, in the context menu of the task,
                // choose Edit. On the Script task editor on Script page, select ReadOnlyVariables,
                // and tick the below properties.
                HostName = (string) Dts.Variables["User::HostName"].Value,
                UserName = (string) Dts.Variables["User::UserName"].Value,
                Password = (string) Dts.Variables["User::Password"].Value,
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = (string) Dts.Variables["User::SshHostKeyFingerprint"].Value
            };

            try
            {
                using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    // As WinSCP .NET assembly has to be stored in GAC to be used with SSIS,
                    // you need to set path to WinSCP.exe explicitly, if using non-default location.
                    session.ExecutablePath = @"C:\winscp\winscp.exe";

                    // Connect
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    // Upload files
                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions);

                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    bool fireAgain = false;
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, null, 
                            string.Format("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName),
                            null, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    }
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, null,
                    string.Format("Error when using WinSCP to upload files: {0}", e),
                    null, 0);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Martin Prikryl .. Can we use above method to get files from SFTP server as well? I have used below statement to get the files from WinSCP folder 'my_data'   transferResult = session.GetFiles("/my_data/ABC_EMP*",@"G:\TestFolder\Download\");  It's giving me an error message like "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" Kindly suggest

Comment: @vikrantrana Yes you can. If you have a problem, post a new question and make sure you include the actual exception message (the inner exception of *"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"*) or a session log file (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: See also WinSCP article [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_net_exception_thrown_target_invocation) or Stack Overflow question [SSIS C# 2012 Script Task referring WinSCPnet.dll fails when run from SQL Server Agent with “Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34345160/850848).

Answer (score 2):

Install **WinSCP** and then create a folder where you want a file from client or put the file.Then Open a Execute Process Task and then go to **Expression** tab and set the **Executable** and **Arguments** with below codes(Please change accordingly).
Write this code in notepad and save as winscp.txt at the path C:\path\to\winscp.txt.

**Open sftp://Host_Name:Password@apacsftp01.mftservice.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="**

**get -delete /home/client/Share/MediaData/Media_file.xlsx**

[image]

**exit**