# Fetch files from SFTP location using SQL stored procedure in AWS RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-rds, sftp

I have an AWS RDS instance SQL server and CSV files in an SFTP location. Need to pull these CSV files and load to a table in the RDS instance SQL server. I am thinking of writing a stored procedure but I am not completely aware of the support functionalities needed to fetch the files from SFTP in a SQL stored procedure especially because the SQL server is not on my local machine and hence the regular solutions I find online is not applicable.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know what FTP is - while it's possible you could implement something using CLR, I don't even know if that's supported in RDS. What you should be looking at is an application or script that can both pull from FTP and push the files to SQL Server. If you don't have a server where this type of script can run, I'm sure you can rent one, Amazon has all kinds of cloud/web services.

Comment: SQL Server has Integration Services (SSIS) for such tasks

Comment: See [Connecting to SFTP via SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34406676/850848).