# SSIS WinSCP C# script task running but not doing anything

Tags: c#, ssis, sftp, winscp, script-task

My code is not throwing any error but it is not doing anything at all.

I'm trying to connect to a SFTP server, the task itself is not showing any error but it is not accessing/getting the file stored in a specific directory.

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using WinSCP;
#endregion

namespace ST_t5fbgt5564cf3a165da70892d8c435v
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public int Main()
        {
            try
            { 
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                PortNumber = xx
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                const string remotePath = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                const string localPath = @"C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

                RemoteFileInfo latest =
                    directoryInfo.Files
                        .Where(file => !file.IsDirectory)
                        .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                if (latest == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No found");
                }

                session.GetFiles(
                    RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(latest.FullName), localPath).Check();
            }
                return 0;
        }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: (0)", e);
                return 1;

            }
            }


        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Is anything wrong with my code? am i missing anything?

---

EDIT:

[image]

---

EDIT #2

I was able to print log messages and this is the error:

```
Error: Error: WinSCP.SessionLocalException: The version of C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe (5.15.3.0) does not match version of this assembly C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WinSCPnet\v4.0_1.7.2.11087__2271ec4a3c56d0bf\WinSCPnet.dll (5.17.10.0).
   in WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess.CheckVersion(String exePath, FileVersionInfo assemblyVersion)
   in WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess..ctor(Session session, Boolean useXmlLog, String additionalArguments)
   in WinSCP.Session.Open(SessionOptions sessionOptions)
   in ST_2u7fsdf8fdsfkjgd998fsdf9ss.ScriptMain.Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to your question is: Do some logging!

See the the [WinSCP SSIS example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis):

- Use [`Dts.Events.FireInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtscomponentevents.fireinformation) a lot.
- Put `try`/`catch` around your whole code and log all exceptions:

  ```
  try
  {
      // The code
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Dts.Events.FireError(
          0, null, $"Error when using WinSCP to upload files: {e}", null, 0);
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by downloading the correct version of the application.

Comment: Which the correct version?